# Figure window resize issue Matplotlib - toolbar dissapears

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize

When I try to resize the figure window in Matplotlib, the toolbar dissapears. Example screenshot given below. Is this a bug or is there a setting missing from my script ?

- matplotlib version: 1.5.1
- numpy 1.11.1
- python 2.7
- Windows 7

very minimal code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.random.randint(0,5,10)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Sorry images look blured, but hopefully you can see the toolbar shrinking as I resize.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this. It appears to be a problem with the matplotlib backend TkAgg. You can change the backend to a different one?

Comment: Which other backend should I use ? 'agg' doesn't produce any output. the others (e.g. wxagg) I think requires dependencies.

Comment: I personally use qt4Agg. It can be a bit of a pain to get running properly but once you do it looks much better IMO.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is not there on qt4Agg.